# SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException despite using a writable DB

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

In a Android App i created the method `saveItem()` to persist a `Media`object to Database. This fails despite using `SQLiteDatabase.getWritableDatabase()` with the following Exception:
`SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database (code 1032)`

Here is my Method:

```
public void saveItem(Media media) {
    // Gets the data repository in write mode
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    // Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaContract.MediaEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ID, media.getId().toString());
    values.put(MediaContract.MediaEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, media.getTitle());
    values.put(MediaContract.MediaEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TEASER, media.getTeaser());
    values.put(MediaContract.MediaEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TYPE, media.getType());
    values.put(MediaContract.MediaEntry.COLUMN_NAME_THUMB_URL, media.getThumbnail_url());
    values.put(MediaContract.MediaEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DATA, new Gson().toJson(media.getData()));
    values.put(MediaContract.MediaEntry.COLUMN_NAME_UPDATED_AT, dbHelper.convertFromDateTime(media.getUpdated_at()));

    db.insert(MediaContract.MediaEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}
```

I observed, that this Exceptions appears not everytime.

Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Where is the db located? Does it live on an external source, such as an SD card?

Comment: it is stored localy. `db` is a normal `SQLiteOpenHelper`

Comment: The memory is not full before the exception occurs. Further more db.isReadOnly() is false.

Comment: I think this is because you have already called `SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();` before in some other method and have not closed it. I think you should not have `SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();` inside the method but it should be in the adapter.